# I import and compile FBReaderJ on eclipse But many error occurred

Tags: android, eclipse

(1)I downloaded the FBReaderJ-sources from http://www.fbreader.org, but I'm having a difficult time importing and compiling FBReaderJ in Eclipse as an Android Project.

I did Run ndk-build  in my project catalog from cygwin so I make  file libDeflatingDecompressor.so and libLineBreak.so in libs directory

But `R.java` is missing; why doesn't the source include it? I know `R.java` changes automatically, but even so that is possible from an existing file or by creating a new project in the workspace.

How do I fix it? Is this related to `local.properties`?
In My Computer sdk and ndk and cygwin is installed 
And my local.properties is saved as
sdk.dir = /android/android-sdk_r08-windows/android-sdk-windows
ndk.dir = /android/android-ndk-r5b

What Problem?

(2) I resolved above problem of missig R.java so I get gen/R.Java
But I got Building failed.

Below ant result

What Problem in main.xml?

C:\FBReaderJ-sources>ant

Buildfile: C:\FBReaderJ-sources\build.xml
.
.
.
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...

```
 [null] C:\FBReaderJ-sources\res\layout\main.xml:8: error: No resource ident
```

ifier found for attribute 'fadeScrollbars' in package 'android'

BUILD FAILED

C:\android\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:
306: null returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds

/res/layout/main.xml

```
org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.view.ZLAndroidWidget
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

below is error meaasge from eclipse console

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at
 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.view.ZLAndroidWidget.getMainAreaHeight(ZLAndroidWidget.java:560)
    at
 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android.view.ZLAndroidWidget.onDraw(ZLAndroidWidget.java:92)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6274)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6277)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:408)
    at
 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.computeLayout(Unknown Source)
.
.
.

(My English isn't great, so try to keep the answers simple)

Comment: Did you import it as an Android project?

Comment: I Resolved  Problems now from versionup FBReader source.  I go to https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ and downloaded the latest version source. Thank you for reading my question

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by shifting the images and xml files from icons folder to drawable folders and it worked for me.